# Generate all combinations of letters and numbers for a specific length string in C?

Tags: c, combinations

I need to create a list of all combinations of lowercase letters and numbers for a certain length, in this case the length needs to be 9. For example: b0a6195c9 
It only needs to generate the combinations for that string length, so only combinations that are 9 characters long.

```
/*
 * C program to find all permutations of letters of a string
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> 

/* Function to swap values at two pointers */
void swap (char *x, char *y)
    {
    char temp;
    temp = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = temp;
}
/*  End of swap()  */

/*  Function to print permutations of string  */
void permute(char *a, int i, int n)
{
    int j;
    if (i == n)
        printf("%s\n", a);
    else {
        for (j = i; j <= n; j++)
        {
            swap((a + i), (a + j));
            permute(a, i + 1, n);
            swap((a + i), (a + j)); //backtrack
        }
    }
}

/*  The main() begins  */
int main()
{
    char a[20];
    int n;
    printf("Enter a string: ");
    scanf("%s", a);
    n = strlen(a);
    printf("Permutaions:\n"); 
    permute(a, 0, n - 1);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Is some of the working C code I've found that approaches the problem, however if you provide the lowercase alphabet and numbers it will generate strings of that length.

This is the desired kind of output, however I wouldn't want duplicates:

- b0a6195c9
- f8j36sg29
- 8jwb28shg

Comment: Do you want combinations, or permutations?  They are different.

Comment: I'm assuming combinations, for example it might start at aaaaaaaaa... aaaaaaaab then once it reaches z it moves to 0 through to 9 and then moves to the next one

Comment: There are 100 trillion combinations. Each "digit" has 36 possible values and there are 9 "digits", so the number of combinations is 36^9 = 100 trillion.

Comment: I assumed as much, this is why I wanted to generate it once and then store it in a file for later use rather than do it on the fly. No doubt the file would be huge but I thought C might be the best tool for the job in terms of speed

Comment: Assuming UTF-8/ASCII encoding, that's a 914TB file, minimum.

Comment: ...and even if you did find that 900TB drive, and assuming you could write your 9-letter words to it at a rate of a million per second, it would take over 3 years to run.